# Google Spreadsheets Api V4 -> Get Background? PHP

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-api-php-client

I installed the below:

https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client-services

Which is using

https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client-services/tree/master/src/Google/Service/Sheets

What I want to do is:

```
$cellFormat = new Google_Service_Sheets_CellFormat();
$color = $cellFormat->getBackgroundColor();
```

But I can't figure out how to assign the spreadsheet or select the range. And then of course return the response.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find the any documentation for the syntax of google spreadsheets v4 so I solved it using a google APP Script.

First I get the sheet:

```
    var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXXXXSPREADSHEETXXXXXID").getSheets();

var tracker = "NEWXXXXXXSPREADSHEETXXXXXID";
var date = new Date();
var M = date.getMonth();
var Y = date.getFullYear();


var Sheettemp = SpreadsheetApp.openById(tracker);
var SheetTr = Sheettemp.getSheets()[M];

var templateSheet = Sheettemp.getSheetByName('Empty');
Sheettemp.insertSheet(M, {template: templateSheet});
Sheettemp.deleteSheet(SheetTr);

SheetTr = Sheettemp.getSheets()[M];

SheetTr.setName(months[M]);



var ctrak = 1;
var ctrak2 = 1;

M = M + 1;
```

Then I Cycle for the date and record this to an array:

```
    for (var S in Sheet) {

    var A = Sheet[S].getName();

    var data = Sheet[S].getRange("D:D").getValues();

    var start = M + '/' + 1 + '/' + Y;
    var sdate = new Date(start);
    var step = [];
    var lastdate = "";


    for (var i in data) {
        var dateval = data[i][0];
        var dchk = new Date(dateval);
        if (!isNaN(dchk.valueOf())) {


            if (lastdate === "") {
                if (dchk.getMonth() === sdate.getMonth()) {
                    lastdate = dchk;
                    start = i;
                    var MM = (dchk.getMonth() + 1);
                    var DD = dchk.getDate();
                    var YY = dchk.getFullYear();

                    var arrdate = MM + '/' + DD + '/' + YY;
                    var j = parseInt(i) + 1;
                    step.push([j, arrdate]);
                }

            } else {
                if (dchk.toString() !== lastdate.toString()) {

                    lastdate = dchk;

                    var stplng = step.length - 1;
                    if (stplng >= 0) {
                        step[step.length - 1][2] = (i);
                    }

                    var MM = (dchk.getMonth() + 1);
                    var DD = dchk.getDate();
                    var YY = dchk.getFullYear();

                    var arrdate = MM + '/' + DD + '/' + YY;
                    var j = parseInt(i) + 1;
                    step.push([j, arrdate]);
                    start = i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then for every date I get the value of the row and match it to what I need. (I searched for a string here "getValues", rather than getBackgroundColor, as stated in my question):

```
        var count = [];
    var count2 = [];

    for (var r in step) {

        var newrange = "F" + step[r][0] + ":F" + ((step[r][2] !== undefined) ? step[r][2] : "");

        var data2 = Sheet[S].getRange(newrange.toString()).getValues();

        for (var i in data2) {

            if (data2[i][0].indexOf("AN EXAMPLE VALUE") !== -1) {
                if (count[r] === undefined) {
                    count[r] = [];
                    count[r].push(step[r][1]);
                    count[r].push('1');
                    count[r].push(i);
                } else {
                    count[r].push(i);
                }
            }
            if (data2[i][0].indexOf("AN EXAMPLE VALUE 2") !== -1 || data2[i][0].indexOf("AN EXAMPLE VALUE 3") !== -1) {
                if (count2[r] === undefined) {
                    count2[r] = [];
                    count2[r].push(step[r][1]);
                    count2[r].push('2');
                    count2[r].push(i);
                } else {
                    count2[r].push(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Last I set a NEW Spreadsheet Sheet with these values (I suppose this could be on the same original spreadsheet, or maybe an ajax call, not sure if ajax works through the script console)

```
        for (var c in count) {
        var B = count[c][0];
        var C = count[c][1];
        count[c].splice(0, 2);
        var D = count[c].length;
        if (D > 0) {
            var srange = "A" + ctrak + ":D" + ctrak;
            srange = srange.toString();
            var valuestrak = [[C, A, D, B]];
            SheetTr.getRange(srange).setValues(valuestrak);

            ctrak++;
        }
    }
    for (var c in count2) {
        var B = count2[c][0];
        var C = count2[c][1];
        count2[c].splice(0, 2);
        var D = count2[c].length;
        if (D > 0) {
            var srange = "E" + ctrak2 + ":H" + ctrak2;
            srange = srange.toString();
            var valuestrak = [[C, A, D, B]];
            SheetTr.getRange(srange).setValues(valuestrak);

            ctrak2++;
        }
    }
```

Finally I pull the information from my server using the range I set it to:

```
$KEY_FILE_LOCATION = 'client_secret.json';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("xxxx");
$client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
$user_to_impersonate = 'xxx@xx.com';
$client->setSubject($user_to_impersonate);
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']);

$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
$spreadsheetId = 'NEWXXXXXXSPREADSHEETXXXXXID';
$df = date('F');
echo $df . PHP_EOL;

$range = $df . '!A:D';
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$vals = $response->getValues();
$values = [];
if (!empty($vals)) {
    if (is_array($vals)) {
        $values = $vals;
    } else {
        array_push($values, $vals);
    }
}
```